# Is it faster to convert into to varchar or varchar to int when comparing in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables that have IDs that reference the same object. One of those tables stores it as a varchar and the other stores it as an int. I want subquery (or possibly join) these two tables.

```
WHERE foo = CAST(bar AS UNSIGNED)
```

or

```
WHERE CAST(foo AS CHAR) = bar
```

Which one is better?

Edit: Neither of the IDs are indexed.

Comment: Why do you think you need to cast them?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel They are cast implicitly anyway.

Comment: @Psi I know. That's why i ask. If you don't cast explicitly MySQL can choose which way to cast depending on which index to use.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the indexes. If both columns have indexes set, you should cast to `int`, because it only needs to compare 4 bytes. If, however, only the `varchar` column is indexed, cast to `varchar`.

At the end, you should have your query `explain`ed, to see what index gets used, and cast accordingly.

If no index is set, casting to `int` is the better approach in general. However, if there is no index set, it doesn't really matter, you would save much more time by indexing than by choosing the correct way to cast. Except, again, the tables are small. Then, it doesn't really matter either.

In fact, we should take into account not only the costs for comparison, but also for casting: Casting an `int` to a `varchar` is slightly faster than parsing a `varchar` to an `int`. However, comparing a varchar that has at least 4 characters will render that advantage useless. If your values tend to be higher than 999, casting to `int` will be faster. But that now depends on your operating system, the architecture, the instruction set used by your mysql binary and so on. The only way to get a really reliable answer is: Benchmark that situation on the target machine.

Comment: Neither of the IDs are Indexed, do you still recommend casting the varchar to int?

Comment: In this case, it's really hard to say. It depends on a lot of different factors, even the distribution of different values in the tables can matter

Comment: Talking about performance while joining on not indexed columns is like to ask if you should push or pull a car while you could also just drive it :-)

Comment: That is so true @PaulSpiegel :D